# Foreign keys and associations using DataMapper

Tags: ruby, datamapper, ruby-datamapper

I have read this page quite thoroughly:

http://datamapper.org/docs/associations

If the answer is on there, it's simply not expressed in a way I can understand.

I'm very confused about using setting up relationship via Datamapper. The datamapper site above is pretty much all I can find on the topic, and as I've said, it hasn't been particularly helpful.

For example, if I want to create something like the following:

Table: `users`

```
id (primary key)
name
```

Table: `attributes`

```
id (pk)
title
```

Table: `user_attributes`

```
id (pk)
user_id (fk to users.id)
attribute_id (fk to attributes.id)
value
```

This seems simple enough, but it has been prohibitively difficult. Everything I try gives me errors like `No relationships named user_attributes or user_attribute in UserUserAttribute (DataMapper::UnknownRelationshipError)`

Can someone please tell me the class definitions for this simple mapping, and perhaps point me to a better discussion of DataMapper associations? Below is some of what I've tried.

```
class User
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id,   Serial, :key => true
  property :name, String

  has n, :user_attributes, :through=>:attribute
end

class Attribute
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id,   Serial, :key => true
  property :name, String

  has n, :user_attributes, :through=>:user
end

class UserAttribute
  include DataMapper::Resource

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :attribute
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're seeing things like `UserUserAttribute` because DataMapper is trying to auto-generate an anonymous join class.

Here's an article that describes how to make [named many-to-many relationships in DataMapper](http://invalidlogic.com/2010/01/27/named-many-to-many-relationships-in-datamapper/)

You would probably change the example something like this:

- User -> User
- Project -> Attribute
- Collaboration -> UserAttribute

Comment: By specifying the models, parent and child keys, (poor choice of names), I'm slowly getting it to work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your class is UserAttribute, and you're trying to name the relationships with user_attributes.  Get rid of the underscore, and your issue will disappear (or add an underscore to the class name)